# How to return products in stock via API REST using SearchCriteria?

Tags: magento2, api, search-criteria

I have an integration that must get my products in stock via the Magento 2 API using SearchCriteria.

How could I filter it, since it's inside my `custom_attributes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter normally as any other attribute. Use this URL below to request, I'm using the rule **"if it's greater than 0 than"** to get products, and I put the limit of 50 products. The counting of total products is included during the return as you can see in the image.

```
https://www.mystore.com/ca_en/rest/all/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=is_in_stock&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=0&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=gt&
searchCriteria[pageSize]=50
```

[image]

Comment: could you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313448/magento-2-2-6-disk-space-utilization-very-fast